# In the Horcrux Cave, was the Aguamenti spell too fundamentally weak to work?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

I'm trying to ascertain if when Harry's spell (*aguamenti*) in the Horcrux cave was blocked by voldemort's protections, if it was too 'low level' a spell to have ever worked and Harry would have needed to know a more powerful spell ([Aqua Eructo](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Aqua_Eructo)?). Or if Harry simply needed to cast it better than Voldemort cast his protection?

Here by better casting or a better spell I mean that the water would have lasted long enough to be drunk. Surely there is a way to overcome the anti-water protections in place?

Comment: Could the downvoters let me know how I could improve my question, please?

Comment: I'm not sure (I upvoted :) ) but I saw a pattern in the last couple of months where questions that are (or seem to be) asked from "incorrect assumption" point of view get severely DVed. (e.g. Q='why is X' when A='because X is false`)

Comment: @DVK Thanks for the explanation. I shall endeavour to research more thoroughly before asking in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actally, Aguamenti **did** indeed work.

Voldemort's protections simply vanished any water that was produced (successfully) by Harry.

> "Aguamenti!" he shouted, jabbing the goblet with his wand. **The goblet filled with clear water;** Harry dropped to his knees beside Dumbledore, raised his head, and brought the glass to his lips — but it was empty. Dumbledore groaned and began to pant. "But I had some — wait — Aguamenti!" said Harry again, pointing his wand at the goblet. **Once more, for a second, clear wa-ter gleamed within it, but as he approached Dumbledores mouth, the water vanished again.** "Sir, I'm trying, I'm trying!" said Harry desperately, but he did not think that Dumbledore could hear him; he had rolled onto his side and was drawing great, rattling breaths that sounded agoniz-ing. **"Aguamenti —Aguamenti —AGUAMENTI!"
>   The goblet filled and emptied once more.** (*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 26: The Cave)

While it's not clear from canon, I don't think any "stronger" spell would have worked - the spells to produce water are not designed or concerned with what happens to the water AFTER it appears (e.g. they don't create "unvanishable" water).

Comment: I might edit again to clarify my point (more to make the question flow) my logic is in it's roughest form: All spells can be countered/overcome, the reason the water vanished was a spell, ergo some water summoning spell would have made the water last.

Comment: @Pureferret - I think I know what you are aiming at. I'm not aware of a spell to KEEP the water that was summoned from being Vanished, nor one to create "unvanishable" water. While no canon proof exists, most likely, the water would have vanished from Dumbledore's mouth even if it kept coming.

Comment: I recently added this as a possibility on similar question - it was regarding Golpalott's Law: perhaps the spell worked fine, but the water produced by it is undrinkable - counting as food/nourishment. This isn't said in the books, but I don't remember of any case where a character drinks water from the Aguamenti Charm: so maybe it can be summoned, but not drank - if it is to be drank, it vanishes; also, it may have been a spell by Voldemort to force people into going to the lake for water, and thus get killed by inferi - rendering their possession of the horcrux pointless.