# Do Hogwart's students have access to a unified list of spells?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

You go to Hogwart's to learn (or defeat evil, you can't have both...unless you're Hermione), you are given books for this purpose. As you go up in your school years you gain access to more and more powerful spells from classes and lessons.

I can imagine it's a struggle to keep up to speed on what spell is more powerful than the other, and that's not to mention all the spells *not* listed in any of your text books or mentioned in.

Is there then a codified list of all spells? A Magic-Wikia page? A Spell-Dewey decimal system? At the least a 'level' system?

Comment: Possibly available as a book in the Ministry of Magic?

Comment: Could the downvoter let me know how I could improve my question, please?

Comment: I think it's called "the Library." That Restricted Section has some *especially* interesting lists of spells. :)

Comment: A library is hardly a 'unified list'. I'd want somethign I could at least apply a regex to so I could find all [water spells](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22871/in-the-horcrux-cave-was-the-aguamenti-spell-too-fundamentally-weak-to-work)...

Comment: Finding ALL spells would seem difficult, since it is apparently possible to create new spells. We learned in Halfblood Prince that Snape apparently created a such a spell.

Comment: @woodchips but eventually I'd imagine it being added to such a list

Answer (score 2):

I should imagine that there is a list that of spells that the professors are required to teach the students, and it would be regulated by the Ministry of Magic.

Comment: I imagine that would be a good starting place.